# How to setup custom dimensions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, google-tag-manager

I have been working to track the user visiting my website with their userID. I am able to see the user by using user explorer in the GA View. But i want to fetch the data over the API to do achieve this i came to know that we have to implement custom dimensions in Google Analytics and then by using that dimension we can fetch the data over the API as well. I have tried sending the data using three ways but none of them seems to be working.
1. Universal Analytivs
2. GTAG.JS
3. Google Tag Manager
I have tried to debug the data as well using Google Tag Assistant Chrome Extensions and screenshots are attached below.

Snippet 1 using Google Universal Analytics

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-125456669-1', 'auto');

ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('set', 'userId', '@Session["CompanyCode"].ToString()#@Session["MembersId"].ToString()'); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
ga('set', 'dimension1', '@Session["CompanyCode"].ToString()#@Session["MembersId"].ToString()');
ga('set', 'dimension2', '@Session["CompanyCode"].ToString()');
</script>
```

Snippet 2 using Google TAg Manager.js

```
<script>
        var dataLayer = [{
            'userID': '@Session["CompanyCode"].ToString()#@Session["MembersId"].ToString()',
            'companyCode':'@Session["CompanyCode"].ToString()'
        }];
    </script>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
}); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-N59M6H8');</script>
```

But one i went to Behaviour > All Page and Select UserID from Secondary Dimension no record is shown

Comment: They need to be sent with an existing hit, or "set" prior to the pageview command to send with all hits on the page
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets#sending_data

Same applies to GTM, you would send them along with a pageview or event.

Comment: @BronwynV Followed your instruction and data is being set first and then i am sending pageview.
Should i wait for 24 hours or it will start showing result immediately ?

Comment: @BronwynV Can you help me please for setting this up using Google Tag Manager

Comment: I'm not good with explaining the GTM stuff, even though i know how to set them up.
Not sure if the following page in the Help Center is helpful to you or not
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164990?hl=en